# Flutter Firebase Login is not Successful

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Firebase Authentication: email/Password was already set to Enabled. Realtime Database: users records exist. Email and Password: thoroughly checked and verified correct.
below are the code for this issue;

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
      void loginUser(BuildContext context) async {
        final User? firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailTextEditingController.text,
          password: passwordTextEditingController.text,
        )
                .catchError((errMsg) {
          displayTostMessage("Error: " + errMsg.toString(), context);
        }))
            .user;
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
          userRef
              .child(firebaseUser.uid)
              .once()
              .then((value) => (DataSnapshot snap) {
                    if (snap.value != null) {
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, HomeScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
                      displayTostMessage("You are logged in", context);
                    } else {
                      _firebaseAuth.signOut();
                      displayTostMessage(
                          "No info exist. Please creat an account", context);
                    }
                  });
        } else {
          displayTostMessage("Erro Accured, Can't be Signed-in", context);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. Which specific line in the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? Is there an error message? If not, did you already set breakpoint and step through the code in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Call this method to login, Hope it will help you.

```
Future<User?> fireLogin(String email, String password) async {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    try {
      final loggedInUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      AppSharedPreference().saveUserId(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
      print(_auth.currentUser!.uid);

      if (loggedInUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/bottomNavBar');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```